# "column" IS NOT NULL in query does not throw error when column does not exist

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, notnull

In my PHP unit tests, I am using an SQLite in-memory database, which contains the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "battlegroup_request" (
  "id" INTEGER NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "battlegroupID" INTEGER NULL,
  "inviterID" INTEGER NULL,
  "inviteeID" INTEGER NULL
)
```

When I execute the following query with two integer bindings;

```
SELECT *
FROM "battlegroup_request"
WHERE "inviteeid" = ? AND
  "inviter" IS NOT NULL AND
  "battlegroupid" = ?
LIMIT 1
```

The query returns one result, but I expect it to throw an error, since the column `inviter` does not exist. Is this expected behaviour of SQLite? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using PDO, the connection was created as follows:

```
new PDO(
    'sqlite::memory:',
    null,
    null,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    )
);
```

(These options are [Laravel](http://www.laravel.com/)'s default, which is the framework we're using.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use something like:

```
SELECT "inviter" IS NOT NULL FROM battlegroup_request
```

it will return TRUE if column `inviter` did not exist, because SQLite will treat `"inviter"` as simply string value (and it is certainly not `NULL` here).

However, if you drop double quotes:

```
SELECT inviter IS NOT NULL FROM battlegroup_request
```

it will raise exception if column `inviter` did not exist.

**EDIT**: Using backticks also forces SQLite to treat it as name (not a string):

```
SELECT `inviter` IS NOT NULL FROM battlegroup_request
```

will raise an exception if column `inviter` did not exist.

Comment: I don't think so, not on SQLite side. You may need to check Laravel docs. If I were you, I would patch framework to NOT escape table and/or column names if they do not really need escaping (don't contain spaces and such).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have patched the framework to use backticks for SQLite, which seems to work as expected. It may not be best practice, but it's a good workaround until they make this optional in SQLite itself.

Comment: glad it worked for you. I will update my answer to mention backticks